# Second order constant coeffient ODE with tan on the right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following differential equation using the trial function method:
$$
y'' + 4y = 2\cdot \tan 2t
$$
I've found the general solution of the homogenous equation ($y_H = A\cdot \sin 2t + D\cdot \cos 2t$). My problem is that I don't know how to choose the trial function for the particular solution in the case when the RHS is the quotient of two "nice" functions. It is also not clear to me if there is resonance in this case.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried, for example, method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)?

Answer (score -3):

For linear equations, the inhomogenous equation of second order can be thought of as a  solution until $t'< t$, and then given a continuous series of kicks to change $$y'(t'+dt)= y(t')+ \text{rhs}(t')dt'$$ while $y(t)$ unchanged, such that the curve is approximated by secants continuously lined up.

This is accomplished by the fundamental distributional solution with $$y,y'=0, t<0, y=\sin(2t), t>0$$ yielding $$y'(t)=0,t<0, \cos(t),t>0, \qquad y''(t)=0,t<0, -4\sin(t), t>0.$$

$$(\partial_{t,t} + 4) \ H(t) \ \sin(2 t) =\delta(t) $$

Without proof, by differentiation

$$y(t) = \int_0^t \sin(2(t-s) \ r(s) \ ds,  \quad t>0 $$

$$ \frac{\partial ^2}{(\partial t)^2}\left(\int_0^t \sin (2\ s) \  r(t-s) \, ds\right)\ , \quad  ( r , r' )(0) =0 $$